# Candlestick Charts "choppy" "uneven"

Tags: chart

beginner question here:

Why are those candlesticks so choppy? What did i miss? In Crypto, i.e. Bitcoin, the candlesticks are more even. - see first picture.

But also, some time frames do not overlap with each other. How can that be? - see second picture

1. Stocks - choppy candlesticks:

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Bitcoin - even candlestick, but also not matching timeframe price change:

   [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your second chart is zoomed in whilst your first chart is zoomed out. If I zoomed into certain areas of your first chart it would look similar to your second chart.

Secondly, in the first chart, there are some gaps. These gaps usually occur when one period of trading closes and the next one opens, sometime the price can gap up on the open if there has been strong demand in one direction. These gaps can also occur in normal continuous trading but are a lot rarer!